# Form Validation Required error getting catched when empty but not when is not set in GET parameter passed as key value pairs

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I am developing RESTful APIs in Codeigniter. It's HTTP method is GET and the parameter I am taking as ?key=value&key2...

```
$val_data = $this->input->get();
$this->form_validation->set_data($val_data);
$this->form_validation->set_rules('oauth_token','Oauth token','required|trim');

if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
{
  $response = ['status'=>'ERROR','data'=>['message'=>$this->form_validation->error_array()]];
  $http_code = 400;
}
```

When the key is passed without value, error message is getting displayed for key is required, but when the key itself is not passed. The required key error message doesn't get displayed.
I wan't to display required error message even when the key itself is not passed.
Please help.

Comment: you should consider using `post` method instead, it will also send the empty key. Or you could manually set all the key on the backend if you still want to use `get` method.